# Use libpng static lib in ImageMagick/GraphicsMagick

Tags: macos, imagemagick, static-libraries

I'd like to compile a executable that contains imagemagick and it's delegate libraries like libpng to ease distribution. I easily compile imagemagick into my app but it always seems to use the dynamic libs.

I installed both dynamic and static delegate libs using macports. Is there a way to tell ImageMagick to use the static ones instead of the dynamic?

I'm currently using the following configure parameters:

> ./configure --prefix=/opt/local
>   --with-quantum-depth=8 --disable-installed --disable-dependency-tracking --without-x --without-perl --enable-static --disable-shared --with-jpeg --with-tiff CPPFLAGS="$CPPFLAGS"
>   LDFLAGS="$LDFLAGS" CFLAGS="$CFLAGS"
>   --disable-openmp --disable-openmp-slow

Thanks,
Rui

Comment: Hum, I guess I'll just try to bundle the dynamic libs with the .app. Probably a lot easier to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I couldn't find a solution to this anywhere. Basically I ended up compiling all delegate projects from the scratch and including the *.dylib files inside the app bundle.